# Subgroups inside of a table

Tags: tables, grouping

I'm trying to create the following table so that the parts marked in red are listed as subgroups with indent while the others are unindented.

[image]

I have tried multicolumn. However, it worked only partially.

Here is the latex code of the current table:
'''

```
\begin{table*}[hbt]
\centering
\caption{Recipient, Donor, and Kidney Transplant Characteristics of the Study Population (n=27814) and the corresponding p-values from the Univariate Cox Regression Proportional Hazards Model}
\label{tab:Characteristics }
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Covariate}                        & \textbf{Mean+SD/ n (\%)} & \textbf{P Value} \\ \midrule
Recipient’s age (years)                   & 47.09$\pm$12.44              & \textless{}0.005 \\
Recipient’s BMI (kg/m2)                   & 26.79$\pm$5.35               & \textless{}0.005 \\
Recipient’s blood type                    &                           & 0.01             \\
O                                         & 12616 (45.36\%)           &                  \\
A                                         & 10049 (36.13\%)           &                  \\
B                                         & 3499 (12.58\%)            &                  \\
AB                                        & 1206 (4.34\%)             &                  \\
A1                                        & 346 (1.24\%)              &                  \\
A2                                        & 60 (0.22\%)               &                  \\
A1B                                       & 30 (0.11\%)               &                  \\
A2B                                       & 7 (0.03\%)                &                  \\
Unknown                                   & 1 (0.00\%)                &                  \\
Recipient’s sex                           &                           & 0.06             \\
Male                                      & 16398 (58.96\%)           &                  \\
Female                                    & 11416 (41.04\%)           &                  \\
Recipient's ethnicity                     &                           & 0.24             \\
White                                     & 16331 (58.72\%)           &                  \\
Black or African American                 & 5721 (20.57\%)            &                  \\
Hispanic/Latino                           & 3731 (13.41\%)            &                  \\
Asian                                     & 1599 (5.75\%)             &                  \\
American Indian or Alaska Native          & 252 (0.91\%)              &                  \\
Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander & 116 (0.42\%)              &                  \\
Other                                     & 64 (0.24\%)               &                  \\
Donor's age (years)                       & 39.38$\pm$12.40              & \textless{}0.005 \\
Donor’s blood type                        &                           & 0.14             \\
O                                         & 15258 (54.86\%)           &                  \\
A                                         & 5445 (19.58\%)            &                  \\
B                                         & 3283 (11.80\%)            &                  \\
AB                                        & 2767 (9.95\%)             &                  \\
A1                                        & 494 (1.78\%)              &                  \\
A2                                        & 403 (1.45\%)              &                  \\
A1B                                       & 132 (0.47\%)              &                  \\
A2B                                       & 30 (0.11\%)               &                  \\
Unknown                                   & 2 (0.01\%)                &                  \\
Donor's sex                               &                           & 0.36             \\
Male                                      & 14863 (53.44\%)           &                  \\
Female                                    & 12951 (46.56\%)           &                  \\
Donor recipient-gender match              &                           & 0.45             \\
Yes                                       & 14067 (50.58\%)           &                  \\
No                                        & 13747 (49.42\%)           &                  \\
Num of A mismatches at transplant         & 1.09 $\pm$ 0.76              & \textless{}0.005 \\
Num of B mismatches at transplant         & 1.21 $\pm$ 0.76              & \textless{}0.005 \\
Num of DR mismatches at transplant        & 0.94 $\pm$ 0.73              & \textless{}0.005 \\
Num of HLA mismatches at transplant                       & 3.24 $\pm$ 1.83   & \textless{}0.005 \\
Total Cold Ischemic Time (hours)          & 12.09 $\pm$ 11.09            & \textless{}0.005 \\
Duration of hospitalization after transplant (days)       & 5.91$\pm$2.22     & \textless{}0.005 \\
Elapsed time between first dialysis and transplant (days) & 841.08$\pm$670.09 & \textless{}0.005 \\
Serum Creatinine at Discharge             & 2.55$\pm$2.31                & \textless{}0.005 \\
Serum creatinine at 6 months              & 1.41$\pm$0.51                & \textless{}0.005 \\
Serum creatinine at 1 year                & 1.40$\pm$0.47                & \textless{}0.005 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}%
\end{table*}
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To minimize typing two environments were defined: for non-indented entries (`NoIndent`)  and for indented ones (`Indent`).

The second has as an optional parameter to enter the desired indentation (default =0pt).

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm, showframe]{geometry} % fit the table into a page


%*************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{environ}% define enviroments

\NewEnviron{NoIndent}{% no indent
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}R{0.4\linewidth}C{0.4\linewidth}C{0.3\linewidth}@{}}
        \BODY
    \end{tabular*}%
}

\NewEnviron{Indented}[1][0pt]{% indented, default =0 pt
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{#1}}R{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-#1}C{0.4\linewidth}C{0.3\linewidth}@{}}
        \BODY
    \end{tabular*}%
}
%***************************************


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[hbt]
    \centering
    \caption{Recipient, Donor, and Kidney Transplant Characteristics of the Study Population (n=27814) and the corresponding p-values from the Univariate Cox Regression Proportional Hazards Model}
    \label{tab:Characteristics }
    \begin{NoIndent}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Covariate}                        & \textbf{Mean+SD/ n (\%)} & \textbf{P Value} \\ \midrule
        Recipient’s age (years)                   & 47.09$\pm$12.44              & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Recipient’s BMI (kg/m2)                   & 26.79$\pm$5.35               & \textless{}0.005 \\[0.3ex]
        Recipient’s blood type                    &                           & 0.01             \\
    \end{NoIndent}%

    \begin{Indented}[20pt]
        O                                         & 12616 (45.36\%)           &                  \\
        A                                         & 10049 (36.13\%)           &                  \\
        B                                         & 3499 (12.58\%)            &                  \\
        AB                                        & 1206 (4.34\%)             &                  \\
        A1                                        & 346 (1.24\%)              &                  \\
        A2                                        & 60 (0.22\%)               &                  \\
        A1B                                       & 30 (0.11\%)               &                  \\
        A2B                                       & 7 (0.03\%)                &                  \\
        Unknown                                   & 1 (0.00\%)                &                  \\
    \end{Indented}% 
        
        \begin{NoIndent}
        Recipient’s sex                           &                           & 0.06            
        \end{NoIndent}%

        \begin{Indented}[20pt]
        Male                                      & 16398 (58.96\%)           &                  \\
        Female                                    & 11416 (41.04\%)           &                  \\
        \end{Indented}% 
    
        \begin{NoIndent}
        Recipient's ethnicity                   &                           & 0.24             \\
        \end{NoIndent}%
                
        \begin{Indented}[20pt]
        White                                     & 16331 (58.72\%)           &                  \\
        Black or African American                 & 5721 (20.57\%)            &                  \\
        Hispanic/Latino                           & 3731 (13.41\%)            &                  \\
        Asian                                     & 1599 (5.75\%)             &                  \\
        American Indian or Alaska Native          & 252 (0.91\%)              &                  \\
        Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander & 116 (0.42\%)              &                  \\
        Other                                     & 64 (0.24\%)               &                  \\
        \end{Indented}% %
        
        \begin{NoIndent}
        Donor's age (years)                       & 39.38$\pm$12.40              & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Donor’s blood type                        &                           & 0.14             \\
        \end{NoIndent}% 
    
    \begin{Indented}[20pt]
        O                                         & 15258 (54.86\%)           &                  \\
        A                                         & 5445 (19.58\%)            &                  \\
        B                                         & 3283 (11.80\%)            &                  \\
        AB                                        & 2767 (9.95\%)             &                  \\
        A1                                        & 494 (1.78\%)              &                  \\
        A2                                        & 403 (1.45\%)              &                  \\
        A1B                                       & 132 (0.47\%)              &                  \\
        A2B                                       & 30 (0.11\%)               &                  \\
        Unknown                                   & 2 (0.01\%)                &                  \\
    \end{Indented}% %

    \begin{NoIndent}
        Donor's sex                               &                           & 0.36             \\
    \end{NoIndent}
            
    \begin{Indented}[20pt]
        Male                                      & 14863 (53.44\%)           &                  \\
        Female                                    & 12951 (46.56\%)           &                  \\
    \end{Indented}% %

    \begin{NoIndent}
            Donor recipient-gender match          &                           & 0.45             \\
    \end{NoIndent}% 
    
    \begin{Indented}[20pt]
        Yes                                       & 14067 (50.58\%)           &                  \\
        No                                        & 13747 (49.42\%)           &                  \\
    \end{Indented}% %

    \begin{NoIndent}
        Num of A mismatches at transplant         & 1.09 $\pm$ 0.76              & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Num of B mismatches at transplant         & 1.21 $\pm$ 0.76              & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Num of DR mismatches at transplant        & 0.94 $\pm$ 0.73              & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Num of HLA mismatches at transplant                       & 3.24 $\pm$ 1.83   & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Total Cold Ischemic Time (hours)          & 12.09 $\pm$ 11.09            & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Duration of hospitalization after transplant (days)       & 5.91$\pm$2.22     & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Elapsed time between first dialysis and transplant (days) & 841.08$\pm$670.09 & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Serum Creatinine at Discharge             & 2.55$\pm$2.31                & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Serum creatinine at 6 months              & 1.41$\pm$0.51                & \textless{}0.005 \\
        Serum creatinine at 1 year                & 1.40$\pm$0.47                & \textless{}0.005 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{NoIndent}% 

\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra column with a length of the indentation and merge any two cells, which should not show indentation.

Also, the table is long and likely spans multiple pages. This can be supported by a few environments (e.g. `longtable`, `xltabular`.) The solution below is based on `xltabular`, which also adds `X` column-type, which is convenient because it automatically calculates remaining width over all columns whose column-type is set to `X`.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=6pt}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{p{15pt} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} X r @{\hspace{0.5em}} r}
  %%% The first head
  \caption{Recipient, Donor, and Kidney Transplant Characteristics of the Study Population (n=27814) and the corresponding p-values from the Univariate Cox Regression Proportional Hazards Model}\label{tab:Characteristics} \\
  \toprule
  \mcc{\textbf{Covariate}}
  & \textbf{Mean+SD/ n (\%)} & \textbf{P Value} \\
  \midrule \endfirsthead
  %%% Subsequent heads
  \caption{Recipient, Donor ... (Continued)} \\
  \toprule
  \mcc{\textbf{Covariate}} & \textbf{Mean+SD/ n (\%)} & \textbf{P Value} \\
  \midrule \endhead

  %%% Subsequent foot
  \bottomrule \\[-0.75\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\itshape Continues on the next page ...}\endfoot
  %%% The last foot
  \bottomrule \endlastfoot

  \mcc{Recipient’s age (years)}              & 47.09$\pm$12.44          & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Recipient’s BMI (kg/m2)}              & 26.79$\pm$5.35           & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Recipient’s blood type}               &                          & 0.01             \\
  & O                                                         & 12616 (45.36\%)          &                  \\
  & A                                                         & 10049 (36.13\%)          &                  \\
  & B                                                         & 3499 (12.58\%)           &                  \\
  & AB                                                        & 1206 (4.34\%)            &                  \\
  & A1                                                        & 346 (1.24\%)             &                  \\
  & A2                                                        & 60 (0.22\%)              &                  \\
  & A1B                                                       & 30 (0.11\%)              &                  \\
  & A2B                                                       & 7 (0.03\%)               &                  \\
  & Unknown                                                   & 1 (0.00\%)               &                  \\
  \mcc{Recipient’s sex}                      &                          & 0.06             \\
  & Male                                                      & 16398 (58.96\%)          &                  \\
  & Female                                                    & 11416 (41.04\%)          &                  \\
  & Recipient's ethnicity                                     &                          & 0.24             \\
  & White                                                     & 16331 (58.72\%)          &                  \\
  & Black or African American                                 & 5721 (20.57\%)           &                  \\
  & Hispanic/Latino                                           & 3731 (13.41\%)           &                  \\
  & Asian                                                     & 1599 (5.75\%)            &                  \\
  & American Indian or Alaska Native                          & 252 (0.91\%)             &                  \\
  & Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander                 & 116 (0.42\%)             &                  \\
  & Other                                                     & 64 (0.24\%)              &                  \\
  \mcc{Donor's age (years)}                  & 39.38$\pm$12.40          & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Donor’s blood type}                   &                          & 0.14             \\
  & O                                                         & 15258 (54.86\%)          &                  \\
  & A                                                         & 5445 (19.58\%)           &                  \\
  & B                                                         & 3283 (11.80\%)           &                  \\
  & AB                                                        & 2767 (9.95\%)            &                  \\
  & A1                                                        & 494 (1.78\%)             &                  \\
  & A2                                                        & 403 (1.45\%)             &                  \\
  & A1B                                                       & 132 (0.47\%)             &                  \\
  & A2B                                                       & 30 (0.11\%)              &                  \\
  & Unknown                                                   & 2 (0.01\%)               &                  \\
  \mcc{Donor's sex}                          &                          & 0.36             \\
  & Male                                                      & 14863 (53.44\%)          &                  \\
  & Female                                                    & 12951 (46.56\%)          &                  \\
  & Donor recipient-gender match                              &                          & 0.45             \\
  & Yes                                                       & 14067 (50.58\%)          &                  \\
  & No                                                        & 13747 (49.42\%)          &                  \\
  \mcc{Num of A mismatches at transplant}    & 1.09 $\pm$ 0.76          & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Num of B mismatches at transplant}    & 1.21 $\pm$ 0.76          & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Num of DR mismatches at transplant}   & 0.94 $\pm$ 0.73          & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Num of HLA mismatches at transplant}  & 3.24 $\pm$ 1.83          & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Total Cold Ischemic Time (hours)}     & 12.09 $\pm$ 11.09        & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Duration of hospitalization after transplant (days)} & 5.91$\pm$2.22 & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Elapsed time between first dialysis and transplant (days)} & 841.08$\pm$670.09 & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Serum Creatinine at Discharge}        & 2.55$\pm$2.31            & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Serum creatinine at 6 months}         & 1.41$\pm$0.51            & \textless{}0.005 \\
  \mcc{Serum creatinine at 1 year}           & 1.40$\pm$0.47            & \textless{}0.005 \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Celdor answer, bur with

- use of tabularray` package
- inserted is one more column for separating `Mean + SD/n (\%)` data

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
  \captionsetup[table]{skip=0.33\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begingroup2
\NewTableCommand\SCtwo{\SetCell{wd=\dimexpr0.4\linewidth+1em+3\tabcolsep, 
                                cmd=\Ident}}
\newcommand*{\Ident}{%
  \raggedright
  \hangafter=1              % <---
  \hangindent=1ex\relax     % <---
                            }

\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Recipient, Donor, and Kidney Transplant Characteristics of the Study Population ($n=27814$) and the corresponding p-values from the Univariate Cox Regression Proportional Hazards Model},
  label={tab:Characteristics}
                ]{colspec = {@{}Q[l, wd=1em] 
                                Q[l, wd=0.4\linewidth]
                                X[r] 
                                X[l]    r},
                 rowsep  = {0pt},
                 row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                 rowhead=1
                 }
    \toprule
  & Covariate                           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Mean + SD/n (\%)
                                                    &               &  P Value      \\
    \midrule
\SCtwo  Recipient’s age (years)         && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 47.09 \pm 12.44
                                                    &               &  \textless{}0.005     \\
\SCtwo  Recipient’s BMI (kg/m2)         && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 26.79 \pm 5.35   
                                                    &               &  \textless{}0.005     \\
\SCtwo  Recipient’s blood type          &&          &               &   0.01        \\
  & O                                   & 12616     &  (45.36\%)    &               \\
  & A                                   & 10049     &  (36.13\%)    &               \\
  & B                                   & 3499      &  (12.58\%)    &               \\
  & AB                                  & 1206      &  (4.34\%)     &               \\
  & A1                                  & 346       &  (1.24\%)     &               \\
  & A2                                  & 60        &  (0.22\%)     &               \\
  & A1B                                 & 30        &  (0.11\%)     &               \\
  & A2B                                 & 7         &  (0.03\%)     &               \\
  & Unknown                             & 1         &  (0.00\%)     &               \\
\SCtwo      Recipient’s sex             &&                      &   & 0.06      \\
  & Male                                & 16398 &  (58.96\%)    &                  \\
  & Female                              & 11416 &  (41.04\%)    &                  \\
  & Recipient's ethnicity               &                       & 0.24             \\
  & White                               & 16331 &  (58.72\%)    &                  \\
  & Black or African American           & 5721  &  (20.57\%)    &                  \\
  & Hispanic/Latino                     & 3731  &  (13.41\%)    &                  \\
  & Asian                               & 1599  &  (5.75\%)     &                  \\
  & American Indian or Alaska Native    & 252   &  (0.91\%)     &                  \\
  & Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander    
                                        & 116   &  (0.42\%)     &                  \\
  & Other                               & 64    &  (0.24\%)     &                  \\
\SCtwo  Donor's age (year)              &&  \SetCell[c=2]{c,$}  39.38 \pm 12.40
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Donor’s blood type              &&      &               & 0.14             \\
  & O                                   & 15258 &  (54.86\%)    &                  \\
  & A                                   & 5445  &  (19.58\%)    &                  \\
  & B                                   & 3283  &  (11.80\%)    &                  \\
  & AB                                  & 2767  &  (9.95\%)     &                  \\
  & A1                                  & 494   &  (1.78\%)     &                  \\
  & A2                                  & 403   &  (1.45\%)     &                  \\
  & A1B                                 & 132   &  (0.47\%)     &                  \\
  & A2B                                 & 30    &  (0.11\%)     &                  \\
  & Unknown                             & 2     &  (0.01\%)     &                  \\
\SCtwo  Donor's sex                     &       &               & 0.36             \\
  & Male                                & 14863 &  (53.44\%)    &                  \\
  & Female                              & 12951 &  (46.56\%)    &                  \\
  & Donor recipient-gender match        &                       & 0.45             \\
  & Yes                                 & 14067 &  (50.58\%)    &                  \\
  & No                                  & 13747 &  (49.42\%)    &                  \\
\SCtwo  Num of A mismatches at transplant   
                                        && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 1.09  \pm  0.76
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Num of B mismatches at transplant   
                                        && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 1.21  \pm  0.76
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Num of DR mismatches at transplant  
                                        && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 0.94  \pm  0.73
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Num of HLA mismatches at transplant 
                                        && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 3.24 \pm  1.83
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Total Cold Ischemic Time (hours)
                                        && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 12.09 \pm  11.09
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Duration of hospitalization after transplant (days)
                                        && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$}  5.91 \pm  2.22
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Elapsed time between first dialysis and transplant days)
                                        &&  \SetCell[c=2]{c,$} 841.08 \pm 670.09
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Serum Creatinine at Discharge   && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$}   2.55 \pm 2.31
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Serum creatinine at 6 months    && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$}  1.41 \pm 0.51
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
\SCtwo  Serum creatinine at 1 year      && \SetCell[c=2]{c,$}  1.40 \pm 0.47
                                                &               & \textless{}0.005 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)